# COUNTIFS with OR condition giving #SPILL! as a result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got the following formula

```
=COUNTIFS(MachineData!N:N,{"*Arlington*","*RenewNorfolk*"}, MachineData!$X:$X,"Y",MachineData!$E:$E,"<>*rinse*", MachineData!$C:$C,">="&$O$15-30, MachineData!C:C,"<="&$O$15+0.999988)
```

On the very first part of the formula I am trying to say "Count if MachineData!N:N is either like Arlington or like RenewNorfolk" but for some reason that specific part of the formula is giving me problems. Can someone help me figure out what the issue is with my syntax? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/countifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic), using the `*IF(S)` type of functions with arrays will make them return an array, so you need to use `SUM` to get one value.

Comment: Sorry, but why exactly am I using a SUM? I have tried the following but it returns 0 which is wrong.

=SUM(COUNTIFS(MachineData!N:N,OR("*Arlington*","*RenewNorfolk*"), MachineData!$X:$X,"Y",MachineData!$E:$E,"<>*rinse*", MachineData!$C:$C,">="&$O$15-7, MachineData!C:C,"<="&$O$15+0.999988))

Comment: You merged my answer with the other wrong answer: you also put `OR` and removed the `*` and the `{}` - you shouldn't. Just use your original formula with `SUM`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I've got another question, why doesn't this work when I say for example <>*Arlington* ? I get double amount of values when using this formula. For example I tried this and it doesn't work 

=SUM(COUNTIFS(MachineData!N:N,{"<>*Arlington*","<>*RenewNorfolk*"}, MachineData!Z:Z,"<>*Patient*",   MachineData!$E:$E,"<>*rinse*", MachineData!$X:$X,"N", MachineData!C:C,"<="&$O$15+0.999988))

Comment: Because one  element of the array contains the values that `"<>*Arlington*"`, and the other that `"<>*RenewNorfolk*"`, and those are summed. I am not sure how could you invert simply - I would just subtract from the total count when *either is like* to get when *neither is like*.