# COUNTIFS counting double amount of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got the following formula that works correctly

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(MachineData!N:N,{"*Arlington*","*RenewNorfolk*"}, MachineData!$X:$X,"Y"))
```

but now if I try to do the same but with "not arlington or not renewnorforlk" I get the wrong answer (it counts double the amount of values that I want to count)

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(MachineData!N:N,{"<>*Arlington*","<>*RenewNorfolk*"}, MachineData!$X:$X,"Y"))
```

what is happening here?

Comment: are you sure? Because the first formula works and it is impossible to be both Arlington and RenewNorfolk at once, so it is counting them somehow if it is either one or the other.

Comment: Let me rephrase:  you will count every instance with that construct since every instance of `RenewNorfolk` will be a `not Arlington` and vice versa.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld how can I change it so it is count if its not "Arlington" or not "RenewNorfolk"?

Comment: You need AND not OR: `=COUNTIFS(MachineData!N:N,"<>*Arlington*",MachineData!N:N,"<>*RenewNorfolk*", MachineData!$X:$X,"Y")`

Comment: What @Rory wrote.  Or a construct like `=SUM(ISERR(SEARCH("*a*",myRange))*ISERR(SEARCH("*b*",myRange)))`

Comment: @Rory Thank you, I hadn't realised that I wanted an "AND" conditions in this case. If you submit your reply as an answer I will select it as a solution yo me problem

Comment: @RonRosenfeld; true as long as the data doesn't contain a typo such as `ArlingtonRenewNorfolk`.

Comment: @JMP Wouldn't that caveat hold true for any method that used wild-cards?

Comment: @JMP so how do you suggest dealing with that issue you state?

Comment: @SolarMike; use **either** `Arlington` **or** `RenewNorfolk`, but **not both**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [COUNTIFS with OR condition giving #SPILL! as a result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68526634/countifs-with-or-condition-giving-spill-as-a-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first statement is equivalent to

`=COUNTIFS(MachineData!N:N,"*Arlington*", MachineData!$X:$X,"Y") + COUNTIFS(MachineData!N:N,"*RenewNorfolk*", MachineData!$X:$X,"Y")`

where the array constant is manually split into it two constituent parts.

If you try this with the second statement

`=COUNTIFS(MachineData!N:N,"<>*Arlington*", MachineData!$X:$X,"Y") + COUNTIFS(MachineData!N:N,"<>*RenewNorfolk*", MachineData!$X:$X,"Y")`

we can see that anything that isn't either `Arlington` or `RenewNorfolk` gets counted by both `COUNTIFS` statements, which isn't what we want the result to be.

The simplest solution is to use

`=COUNTIFS(MachineData!N:N,"<>*Arlington*", MachineData!N:N,"<>*RenewNorfolk*", MachineData!$X:$X,"Y")`

which requires all the criteria to be met for a data item to be counted.